# Difference between nested {} and []

Tags: tcl

Why is it that inside a brace quote, you have to escape **all** braces (that shouldn't count in the nesting), but inside a bracket substitution, you don't have to escape all brackets (that shouldn't count in the nesting).

```
puts "}" ;# ok in top-level (1)
if {1} {puts "}"} ;# but not ok when inside a brace quote (2)

puts {]} ;# ok in top-level (3)
set output [puts {]}] ;# and still ok inside a bracket substitution (4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the interpreter encounters `{` at the beginning of a word, it looks for the matching `}` to get the word (the command name to execute or one of the arguments to send to the command).

But when the interpreter encounters an unescaped `[`, it doesn't look for the matching `]`. It stops parsing the script itself and calls another interpreter recursively. That interpreter starts parsing at the character following the `[`. When it finds the `{` in example 4, it starts quoting mode, so the `]` is treated like a normal character.

So why not call an interpreter recursively when `{` is encountered too, and get rid of the brace-problem in example 2? Because the word you're quoting with braces isn't always a script, and even if it is, it's probably not supposed to be run right away. Brace quoting must be exact; the parser can't treat characters differently based on if they're inside `"`, `[]` etc... or not, like a script parser does.

Comment: At the implementation level, we parse into `[`…`]` sequences in the language parser, and depend on the command compiler to determine what `{`…`}` sequences are to be parsed into.